# elasticsearch index closed cannot use aliases to search

Tags: elasticsearch-dsl

elasticsearch 7.9.3 version defines an alias for the index, after closing the previous index, you can no longer search with the alias, and an error will be reported index_closed_exception, how to solve it

```
POST t222ttt-22/_close
// t222ttt_all is the alias , with ES version 7.9.3
GET t222ttt_all/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  }
}

// response:
{
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [
      {
        "type" : "index_closed_exception",
        "reason" : "closed",
        "index_uuid" : "a_EhkTASSgSO0nsWnIt42A",
        "index" : "t222ttt-22"
      }
    ],
    "type" : "index_closed_exception",
    "reason" : "closed",
    "index_uuid" : "a_EhkTASSgSO0nsWnIt42A",
    "index" : "t222ttt-22"
  },
  "status" : 400
}
```